# Youtube embed player avoiding zindex

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, z-index, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to get an image to be placed over an youtube embedded player. I added the `wmode=transparent` to the url through jQuery to allow the player to accept a zindex. While it loads the image does show over the player but once the page is fully loaded, the player returns on top of the image. What's causing this?

```
<iframe class="one"  id="bottom" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com

/embed/H7D4Ryi2ckg?list=SP0D260F7B6625A6BA&amp;hl=en_US" frameborder="0" 

allowfullscreen></iframe>

<img class="one" id="top" width="560" height="315" 

src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com

/wpf/media-live/photos/000/005/cache/domestic-cat_516_600x450.jpg" alt="" >

<style type="text/css">

    .one {position: absolute; top: 100px;}

    #top{z-index: 9999;}

    #bottom{z-index: 1;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function ()

 $('iframe').each(function()

    var url = $(this).attr("src")

    $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent")

 );

);

</script>
```

Comment: Weird, why do Youtube embeds require &wmode=transparent, when other embeds (vimeo) don't require this to make divs/dialogs above it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `?rel=0` in your iframe src.  It works if you remove `rel=0` from the replace string.

Also you're missing a semicolon terminator after the `var url = ...`

***EDIT***

It works fine after fixing the syntax errors: [meow](http://jsfiddle.net/7nJRg/)

Comment: I took out that section but it still does not work. I updated the code on my question.